# Using enum as a type/interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

While converting an enumerator from JavaScript into TypeScript, I had to add my own enum - `myEnumType`.

If I use such enum as a property type:

```
prop:myEnumType
```

it will be expected that the value must be of type `myEnumType`.

How can we declare a property in TypeScript that represents the enum itself as a type, as opposed to a value of that type?

I'm trying to expose the enum as a type, via an interface property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm trying to expose the enum as a type, via an interface property.

You can *declare* an `enum` e.g. in a `vendor.d.ts`:

```
declare enum MyEnumType {
   Member1,
   Member2,
}
```

## Update

> And how would I then declare a property of the enum as a type, via an interface property?

```
interface Foo {
  prop: MyEnumType
}
```

Comment: And how would I then declare a property of the enum as a type, via an interface property?

Comment: Kind of. I would like to understand what special do you do to achieve that... Is there something special about that `vendor.d.ts` file? Or adding `declare` changes the enum? Could you, please explain the solution?

Comment: These are called *ambient declarations* and I cover them here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/ambient/intro.html

Answer (score 2):

In myEnumType.ts class

```
export enum MyEnumType {
  Member1,
  Member2
}
```

In Foo.ts class

```
import { MyEnumType } from './myEnumType';
export interface Foo {
  prop: MyEnumType;
}
```

Comment: How do we access the enumerated values from the interfaced data?